# Overriding UsersIdService.getUserId() on spartacus 3.x version

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I had overridden  Authservice.getOccUserId() on  Spartacus in 2.x version , on spartacus 3.x version how do I override UsersIdService.getUserId() inject Store on the constructor without getting Circular dependency in DI detected for Store error

Comment: Why do you need store in your UserIdService version?

Comment: @MarcinLasak  I need a function to return  the user token from my store "authStore: Store<AuthState>"  and override UsersIdService.getUserId() with that function

Comment: The service as a name suggests should be responsible only for user id (no token). I would instead try to create separate service that would have store and userIdService as parameters in constructor and group data from those 2 sources there.